# D3 ignore drawing missing value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw stock data to chart where there is a  line which define the previous closing price. I'm trying to draw another line where if the value > previous closing then line is green and if < then red.

the problem is d3 is drawing 2 lines of the same color and not linking them.

the picture and code should make more sense.
[image: <code>the blue part defined shouldn't exist and it's missing data</code>]

```
       this.line = d3Shape.line()
       .x( (d: any) => this.x(d.date) )
       .y( (d: any) => this.y(d.average) );

   this.svg.append('path')
  .datum(this.customTitle)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
  .attr("d", this.line(this.customTitle.filter(function(d){
    return d.average<268;
  })))
  .attr("stroke","red");

  this.svg.append('path')
 .attr("fill", "none")
 .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
 .attr("d", this.line(this.customTitle.filter(function(d){
   return d.average>=268;
 })))
 .attr("stroke", "green");
```

Answer (score -1):

You filter out a set of points in the middle of the green line, but you don't tell anything to d3 that you want it empty -- so it simply connects two closest points, which are on the edges of the red line dip.

Instead, specify `defined` property to the line generator. This way it will know that points exist in the middle, but it will not draw them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
    path {
      fill: none;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var data = d3.range(100).map(function(d){
      return {
        x: d * 1,
        y: Math.cos(4 * Math.PI * d / 100) * 100
      };
    });
    var lineGen = d3.line()
        .x((d) => d.x)
        .y((d) => d.y);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 960)
      .attr("height", 500)
        .attr('viewBox', "0 -100 200 200");

    svg.append("path")
        .style('stroke', 'green')
        .attr("d", lineGen.defined((d, i, data) => {
        var next = data[i + 1];
        if (next) {
                    return next.y < 0 || d.y < 0;
        }
        return d.y < 0;
        })(data));


    svg.append("path")
        .style('stroke', 'red')
        .attr("d", lineGen.defined((d, i, data) => {
        var next = data[i + 1];
        if (next) {
                    return next.y >= 0 || d.y >= 0;
        }
        return d.y >= 0;
        })(data));
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm not sure how would I use defined with my code as it's throwing error. it would be much appreciated if you can show that on my code.